# I'm trying to toggle my class on jQuery with hovering. Why doesn't the CSS change?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, toggle, toggleclass

I have a div that acts as a button that's supposed to glow when it's hovered over.
Here is my entire code (I hope it's not too long.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <title>The Eradicator Virus</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        ::selection {
            background: #FFB7B7;
        }
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Copperplate / Copperplate Gothic Light, Century Gothic, sans-serif;
        }
        p {
            margin: 50px 0 0 0;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 2.5em;
            color: #EE0000;
        }
        .picture {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 150px;
            background-image: url("Viruses.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .title {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-family: "Copperplate", serif;
            color: #EE0000;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 750%;
            background-color: #880000;
        }
        .maroon {
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            background-color: #880000;
        }
        #download {
            width: 170px;
            margin: 50px 50% 0 0;
            padding: 0 6px;
            font-size: 2.5em;
            color: #EE0000;
            border: 3px solid #EE0000;
            background-color: #880000;
        }
        .normalDownload {
            color: #EE0000;
            border: 3px solid #EE0000;
            background-color: #880000;
        }
        .glowingDownload {
            color: #000000;
            border: 3px solid #000000;
            background-color: #EE0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 class="title">The Eradicator Virus</h1>

    <div class="picture"></div>

    <div class="maroon">

        <p>Unleash a sickness that can never be stopped.</p>

        <p>So merciless and efficient that it eliminates a zettabyte each second of control.</p>

        <p>So unstoppable not even the creators know how to remove it.</p>

        <p>So quick that it destroys computers faster than the speed of light.</p>

        <p>Convinced yet? Take command and smack the download button!</p>

        <div id="download">Download</div>

    </div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#download").hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("glowingDownload");
        });

        // $("#download").click(function() {
            // alert("Downloading... 99% Complete");
        // });

    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am sure that jQuery knows about the hovering (I tested it with an alert.)

Comment: It seems OK. Could you explain more?

Comment: This is the first time I've used stackoverflow. Would it be convenient if I gave you all 117 lines of code?

Comment: The toogleClass adds or remove a class from an element the problem in your case is that your glowing and normal download both define same property so the browser will choose any of them

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I don't want to do it in CSS because that change isn't gradual. JQuery makes it appear very smooth. Sorry.

Comment: btw you can use jsbin.com to give examples of code and people who reply can directly modify your code in order to make it work as for answer you have plently of them bellow

Answer (score 1):

Javascript isn't necessary here. Use the css hover attribute, namely:

```
.normalDownload:hover { 
 /* desired css here */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: You really don't want to have jQuery here as noted by @nmac

The problem is the [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Since you have an ID based rule which specifies the rules used in the class rule the ID rule will take precedence and will override the class rule so the class rule will not have any effect

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#download").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("glowingDownload");
  });
});
```

```css
#download {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 50px 50% 0 0;
  padding: 0 6px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #EE0000;
  border: 3px solid #EE0000;
  background-color: #880000;
}
#download.normalDownload {
  color: #EE0000;
  border: 3px solid #EE0000;
  background-color: #880000;
}
#download.glowingDownload {
  color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: #EE0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="download">Download</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `jQuery` you can simply use CSS [**:hover**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). `#download:hover{}`

```css
#download {
     width: 170px;
     margin: 50px 50% 0 0;
     padding: 0 6px;
     font-size: 2.5em;
     color: #EE0000;
     border: 3px solid #EE0000;
     background-color: #880000;
}
#download:hover {
     color: #000000;
     border: 3px solid #000000;
     background-color: #EE0000;
     cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="download">Download</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseenter() and mouseleave() of jquery if you want to use jquery only

```
$('#download').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'#000000', 'border':'3px solid #000000', 'background-color':'#EE0000'});
});
$('#download').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'#EE0000', 'border':'3px solid #EE0000', 'background-color':'#880000'});
});
```